# how to make a list to be used in given methods

Tags: java, collections, pojo

I have an `Arraylist` which has a `Map` in it. I want to convert the list with respect to a key and value pair and store it into an another List.

I have a list which gives output as:

```
List<Map<String, String>> mainList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

{Date=29/01/2018, Type=UNI, Number=17131176}
{Date=29/01/2019, Type=UPS, Number=17592158}
{Date=29/01/2020, Type=CP2, Number=17601558}
{Date=27/01/2015, Type=CP3, Number=17457472}
{Date=27/01/2015, Type=MBY, Number=17112367}
{Date=21/01/2015, Type=CP4, Number=17843672}
```

How can I make this list to be used in these two methods?

```
public void excludeNumbers(List<String> Numbers, Date Date)
public void excludeTypes(List<String> Types, Date Date)
```

Comment: I don't quite see the problems. Do you have any problem passing the list to the function? That might be because you are using List<String> Numbers instead of List<Map<String, String>>. Or are you missing an idea to even pass the list to the functions?

Comment: In your main data, which property stands for the key? Date, Type or Number? Is your key Unique? In order to have Maps, you should have unique keys for the collection.

Comment: @Sossenbinder , i am extarcting data from the CSV file and storing that into map<String,String> and that map into a List<Map<String, String>> but then it don't have any idea how to create different list of Number and Type with respect to a Date.

Comment: I'm still somewhat confused but if you have problems differencing beetween types you might want to create a wrapper class for your Number and Type, so you can clearly differ both. It is usually safer than using strings as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
   excludeNumbers(mainList.stream()
        .map(m -> m.get("Number"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()), date);
    excludeTypes( mainList.stream()
        .map(m -> m.get("Type"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()), date);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it by adapting these 2 methods to:

```
public void excludeNumbers(List<Map<String, String>> Numbers, Date Date);
public void excludeTypes(List<Map<String, String>> Types, Date Date);
```

and then, while your `mainList` is in scope of course:

```
excludeNumbers(mainList,  *>your date here<*)
excludeTypes(mainList,  *>your date here<*)
```